# Windows Phone app Stretch Buttons and align content left

Tags: wpf, windows-phone

I have a grid with buttons which are composed of an image and text. I would like the buttons to fill the grid cell and also have their content aligned left.

This is my code:

```
<Button Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0"   Margin="0,0,0,0" 
        HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" x:Name="BusRoutes"
        Click="BusRoutes_Click">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"  
                Margin="0,0,0,0">
        <Image Width="35" Source="Assets/images/roadmap.png"  Margin="0,0,10,0"/>
        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                   Text="{Binding Path=LocalizedButtonTextResources.BusRoutes,
                                  Source={StaticResource LocalizedStrings}}" />
    </StackPanel>
</Button>
```

The above code makes the button stretch and fill the cell but the content (image and text) are centered. If i change the HorizontalAlignement property to left then i get the content aligned left but not stretched.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set **`HorizontalContentAlignment`** to **`Left`** on Button to make the content align left within button.

```
<Button Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Margin="0,0,0,0" 
        HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" x:Name="BusRoutes"
        Click="BusRoutes_Click" HorizontalContentAlignment="Left">
   .....
</Button/>
```